# Steady-state response in matlab doesn't show all states

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm using MATLAB to get my steady state response for a system (Response of the states), the system has two states but MATLAB only plots 1 whatever I do.

Here's my code:

```
s=tf('s');
J=0.006;
Rm=1.5;
B=0.01;
Lm=15;
Kt=0.7;
Km=0.6;

A=[-Rm/Lm -Km/Lm;Kt/J -B/J];
B=[1/Lm;0];
C=[0 1];
D=[0];
sys=ss(A,B,C,D);    
T=tf(sys); 

[y,t] = step(T);

plot(t, y);
legend('x1', 'x2');
```

Output Plot:

[image: Plot Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation of [`step`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/step.html#zmw57dd0e101215), the output vector `y` is the output response of the system (`y = C*x + D*u`) and not the state trajectories.  The state trajectories are acquired via the third output of `step`.  Also, in order for `step` to return the trajectories, the input must be a state-space (`ss`) model, but you're inputing the transfer function (`tf`) form of the system.  From those two points, the following should provide your desired output:

```
[y,t,x] = step(sys);
plot(t, x);
legend('x1', 'x2');
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but do you know if i can matlab takes specific states and not to choose them by it self ?

Comment: @JenuRudan I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: when using ssdata function on my system it gives different A,B,C,D than hand analysis because it used different states, so can i specify to matlab what to use as states

Comment: @JenuRudan Without knowing exactly what you are doing (in addition to not being a Control System's expert despite dabbling), I can only say that `ssdata` calls `ss` to convert the Transfer Function into a state space model and that "[conversions] to state-space form are not uniquely defined" and "[in] general, it is recommended that you work with state-space (`ss`) or frequency response data (`frd`) models" (for numerical accuracy) (c.f. [Conversion Between Model Types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/conversion-between-model-types.html#f3-997251)).

Comment: @JenuRudan If you want to see all the states then you have to make your C matrix the identity and D matrix a zeros matrix with compatible size such that all states are in the output equation. Then you can see all of them. And you don't need to convert your model to tf.

Comment: @percusse Ah, nice.  I didn't even notice that `C` was a row vector.  Good call!